# DApp using IPFS Ganache and MetaMask

Tags: metamask, ipfs

I am following a tutorial (hosted by dappuniversity) on youtube regarding DApps using IPFS. I have done exactly everything as mentioned in the tutorial but i get this errors:

```
GET https://ipfs.io/ipfs/ 400 () ipfs.io/:1 

App.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at App.js:87
    at f (once.js:25)
    at ConcatStream (add.js:42)
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (index.js:37)
    at ConcatStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:630)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:638)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:594)
    at Duplex.onend (_stream_readable.js:577)
    at Duplex.g (events.js:165)
```

I use MetaMask and it is linked to Ganache.

I installed IPFS  and compiled and migrated the contracted using.

- npm install ipfs --save
- npm install --save ipfs-api
- truffle compile
- truffle migrate --reset

[image: ScreenShot from my Ganache]
Here is the smart contract

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract SimpleStorage {
  string ipfsHash;

  function set(string x) public {
    ipfsHash = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (string) {
    return ipfsHash;
  }
}
```

[Main code on github App.js](https://github.com/dappuniversity/ipfs_image_uploader/blob/master/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you really should add a `catch` clause on this promise:

```
// Get accounts.
this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
  simpleStorage.deployed().then((instance) => {
    this.simpleStorageInstance = instance
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })
    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    return this.simpleStorageInstance.get.call(accounts[0])
  }).then((ipfsHash) => {
    // Update state with the result.
    return this.setState({ ipfsHash })
  })
})
```

That is:

```
.catch(() => {
  console.log('Error deploying contract.')
})
```

Then, you receive the `Cannot read property 'set' of undefined` error at line 87 because of this specific object:

```
this.simpleStorageInstance
```

As you only manipulate the object in only one function other than the call on line 87, there are two possible explanations:

1. The contract is not deployed at all, due to some systemic bug
2. There is a delay and you somehow call `onSubmit` before the contract is deployed

In any scenario, double check the promise above. Logging the execution time might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's point of catching potential errors when you `getAccounts` is important.

Is the `SimpleStorageContract` located at the path `'../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json'` in line 1?

I'm a bit of a React noob, but shouldn't you instantiate `simpleStorageInstance` at the top?